# is there a way of dismissing two uiViewControllers at the same time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

In my swift app I have a UIViewController with a button. This button opens up the UIViewController number 2 and there user has another button. When user presses it - he opens UIViewController number 3. There is also a button and when user presses it - he calls the code:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

and thanks to it the UIViewController number 3 disappears and user sees UIViewController number 2. My question is - is there a way of also dismissing the UIViewController number 2 so that user can come back smoothly from number 3 to number 1?

For now I created a function and call it through protocol:

UIViewController number 2:

```
protocol HandleYourFullRequest: class {
    func hideContainer()
}


class FullRequest: UIViewController, HandleYourFullRequest{

    func hideContainer(){
       self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func exitbuttonaction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("temporarySegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "temporarySegue"){


        if let fullRequestDetails = segue.destinationViewController as? YourFullRequest
        {

            fullRequestDetails.delegateRequest = self
        }

    }
    }



}
```

UIViewController number 3:

```
class YourFullRequest: UIViewController{

    var delegateRequest:HandleYourFullRequest?

    @IBAction func exitbuttonaction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        delegateRequest?.hideContainer()
    }
}
```

But with that solution when user presses the button - the UIViewController number 3 disappears and UIViewController number 2 appears for a second and disappears then. Is there a way of removing number 2 without showing it to the user and point him directly to the number 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still unclear as two which button is wired to which action, but from what I can tell when the dismiss button is pressed on view controller 3 it calls `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)` in view controller number 2.

Try putting this method in view controller 3.

```
@IBAction func exitButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

This will work assuming that both view controllers are presented and not pushed in something like a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use removeLast() function to pop controllers off the stack.

```
@IBAction func doneAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    var vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
    // remove controllers from the stack
    vc?.removeLast()
    vc?.removeLast()
    // Jump back to the controller you want.
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vc!, animated: false)        
}
```

Comment: hmm I tried this solution but when I presses the button - nothing works :) I'm not sure if there's something I could miss?

Comment: Does "nothing works" mean nothing happens? Is your button hooked to the function?

Comment: yes, I see only a print msg that I added right above the `var vc = self.navigationController?...`

Comment: Add `print(vc)` to see if it's nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `popToViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)`

Where `viewController` is the viewController you wish to pop to, in your case, 'UIViewController number 1'.

[popToViewController Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:)

If you don't have a reference to the View Controller, you can get it from `self.navigationController.viewControllers`, it will be the first object in your example.

Comment: can you give me a hint how could I refer to the first element of `self.navigationController.viewControllers`? I tried `popToViewController(self.navigationController.viewControllers.first: UIViewController, animated: Bool)` but it causes some error in my case :(

Comment: @user3766930 Set a breakpoint before you pop the view controller and print out the contents of self.navigationController.viewControllers array. Be useful to see that here. Your view controller hierarchy may not be what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method on UINavigationController called setViewControllers. It takes an array of all the view controllers you want active. You can get all the view controllers on the stack as an array, remove the ones you don't want, then call setViewControllers with the updated array.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, however - could you show me some example, possibly with my current code - of how exactly I could use it? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: if let myNav = self.navigationController{
            var allvc = myNav.viewControllers
            allvc.removeLast()
            allvc.removeLast()
            myNav.setViewControllers(allvc, animated: true)
        }